# Add timestamps to output? pocketsphinx

Tags: wav, speech-to-text, transcription

Been using pocketsphinx to successfully grab transcripts from wav files, and it made sense to me that there would be an argument for adding timestamps. Actually, there are SO MANY arguments in the help file:

```
Arguments list definition:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [DESCR]
-adcdev                                 Name of audio device to use for input.
-agc                    none            Automatic gain control for c0 ('max', 'emax', 'noise', or 'none')
-agcthresh              2.0             Initial threshold for automatic gain control
-allphone                               Perform phoneme decoding with phonetic lm
-allphone_ci            no              Perform phoneme decoding with phonetic lm and context-independent units only
-alpha                  0.97            Preemphasis parameter
-argfile                                Argument file giving extra arguments.
-ascale                 20.0            Inverse of acoustic model scale for confidence score calculation
-aw                     1               Inverse weight applied to acoustic scores.
-backtrace              no              Print results and backtraces to log.
-beam                   1e-48           Beam width applied to every frame in Viterbi search (smaller values mean wider beam)
-bestpath               yes             Run bestpath (Dijkstra) search over word lattice (3rd pass)
-bestpathlw             9.5             Language model probability weight for bestpath search
-ceplen                 13              Number of components in the input feature vector
-cmn                    live            Cepstral mean normalization scheme ('live', 'batch', or 'none')
-cmninit                40,3,-1         Initial values (comma-separated) for cepstral mean when 'live' is used
-compallsen             no              Compute all senone scores in every frame (can be faster when there are many senones)
-debug                                  Verbosity level for debugging messages
-dict                                   Main pronunciation dictionary (lexicon) input file
-dictcase               no              Dictionary is case sensitive (NOTE: case insensitivity applies to ASCII characters only)
-dither                 no              Add 1/2-bit noise
-doublebw               no              Use double bandwidth filters (same center freq)
-ds                     1               Frame GMM computation downsampling ratio
-fdict                                  Noise word pronunciation dictionary input file
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       Feature stream type, depends on the acoustic model
-featparams                             File containing feature extraction parameters.
-fillprob               1e-8            Filler word transition probability
-frate                  100             Frame rate
-fsg                                    Sphinx format finite state grammar file
-fsgusealtpron          yes             Add alternate pronunciations to FSG
-fsgusefiller           yes             Insert filler words at each state.
-fwdflat                yes             Run forward flat-lexicon search over word lattice (2nd pass)
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           Beam width applied to every frame in second-pass flat search
-fwdflatefwid           4               Minimum number of end frames for a word to be searched in fwdflat search
-fwdflatlw              8.5             Language model probability weight for flat lexicon (2nd pass) decoding
-fwdflatsfwin           25              Window of frames in lattice to search for successor words in fwdflat search
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           Beam width applied to word exits in second-pass flat search
-fwdtree                yes             Run forward lexicon-tree search (1st pass)
-hmm                                    Directory containing acoustic model files.
-infile                                 Audio file to transcribe.
-inmic                  no              Transcribe audio from microphone.
-input_endian           little          Endianness of input data, big or little, ignored if NIST or MS Wav
-jsgf                                   JSGF grammar file
-keyphrase                              Keyphrase to spot
-kws                                    A file with keyphrases to spot, one per line
-kws_delay              10              Delay to wait for best detection score
-kws_plp                1e-1            Phone loop probability for keyphrase spotting
-kws_threshold          1               Threshold for p(hyp)/p(alternatives) ratio
-latsize                5000            Initial backpointer table size
-lda                                    File containing transformation matrix to be applied to features (single-stream features only)
-ldadim                 0               Dimensionality of output of feature transformation (0 to use entire matrix)
-lifter                 0               Length of sin-curve for liftering, or 0 for no liftering.
-lm                                     Word trigram language model input file
-lmctl                                  Specify a set of language model
-lmname                                 Which language model in -lmctl to use by default
-logbase                1.0001          Base in which all log-likelihoods calculated
-logfn                                  File to write log messages in
-logspec                no              Write out logspectral files instead of cepstra
-lowerf                 133.33334       Lower edge of filters
-lpbeam                 1e-40           Beam width applied to last phone in words
-lponlybeam             7e-29           Beam width applied to last phone in single-phone words
-lw                     6.5             Language model probability weight
-maxhmmpf               30000           Maximum number of active HMMs to maintain at each frame (or -1 for no pruning)
-maxwpf                 -1              Maximum number of distinct word exits at each frame (or -1 for no pruning)
-mdef                                   Model definition input file
-mean                                   Mixture gaussian means input file
-mfclogdir                              Directory to log feature files to
-min_endfr              0               Nodes ignored in lattice construction if they persist for fewer than N frames
-mixw                                   Senone mixture weights input file (uncompressed)
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       Senone mixture weights floor (applied to data from -mixw file)
-mllr                                   MLLR transformation to apply to means and variances
-mmap                   yes             Use memory-mapped I/O (if possible) for model files
-ncep                   13              Number of cep coefficients
-nfft                   512             Size of FFT
-nfilt                  40              Number of filter banks
-nwpen                  1.0             New word transition penalty
-pbeam                  1e-48           Beam width applied to phone transitions
-pip                    1.0             Phone insertion penalty
-pl_beam                1e-10           Beam width applied to phone loop search for lookahead
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           Beam width applied to phone loop transitions for lookahead
-pl_pip                 1.0             Phone insertion penalty for phone loop
-pl_weight              3.0             Weight for phoneme lookahead penalties
-pl_window              5               Phoneme lookahead window size, in frames
-rawlogdir                              Directory to log raw audio files to
-remove_dc              no              Remove DC offset from each frame
-remove_noise           yes             Remove noise with spectral subtraction in mel-energies
-remove_silence         yes             Enables VAD, removes silence frames from processing
-round_filters          yes             Round mel filter frequencies to DFT points
-samprate               16000           Sampling rate
-seed                   -1              Seed for random number generator; if less than zero, pick our own
-sendump                                Senone dump (compressed mixture weights) input file
-senlogdir                              Directory to log senone score files to
-senmgau                                Senone to codebook mapping input file (usually not needed)
-silprob                0.005           Silence word transition probability
-smoothspec             no              Write out cepstral-smoothed logspectral files
-svspec                                 Subvector specification (e.g., 24,0-11/25,12-23/26-38 or 0-12/13-25/26-38)
-time                   no              Print word times in file transcription.
-tmat                                   HMM state transition matrix input file
-tmatfloor              0.0001          HMM state transition probability floor (applied to -tmat file)
-topn                   4               Maximum number of top Gaussians to use in scoring.
-topn_beam              0               Beam width used to determine top-N Gaussians (or a list, per-feature)
-toprule                                Start rule for JSGF (first public rule is default)
-transform              legacy          Which type of transform to use to calculate cepstra (legacy, dct, or htk)
-unit_area              yes             Normalize mel filters to unit area
-upperf                 6855.4976       Upper edge of filters
-uw                     1.0             Unigram weight
-vad_postspeech         50              Num of silence frames to keep after from speech to silence.
-vad_prespeech          20              Num of speech frames to keep before silence to speech.
-vad_startspeech        10              Num of speech frames to trigger vad from silence to speech.
-vad_threshold          2.0             Threshold for decision between noise and silence frames. Log-ratio between signal level and noise level.
-var                                    Mixture gaussian variances input file
-varfloor               0.0001          Mixture gaussian variance floor (applied to data from -var file)
-varnorm                no              Variance normalize each utterance (only if CMN == current)
-verbose                no              Show input filenames
-warp_params                            Parameters defining the warping function
-warp_type              inverse_linear  Warping function type (or shape)
-wbeam                  7e-29           Beam width applied to word exits
-wip                    0.65            Word insertion penalty
-wlen                   0.025625        Hamming window length

INFO: continuous.c(295): Specify '-infile <file.wav>' to recognize from file or '-inmic yes' to recognize from microphone.
```

But in terms of everything having to do with time, I was unable to find an argument intended for adding timestamps.

Comment: Does [CMU Sphinx / Forums / Help: How to get word timestamps with pocketsphinx?](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/30f21509/) answer your question? "The option "-time" is used in command line tool pocketsphinx_continuous. "